# How to get accessToken of React Native GoogleSignIn?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, google-signin

I am not able to get accessToken, i need it in my backend api.

When i try this,

```
googleLogin = () => {

  GoogleSignin.signIn()
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("TEST "+JSON.stringify(data));
      var postData = {
        access_token: data.accessToken,
        code: data.idToken,
      };

      let axiosConfig = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "Accept": "application/json",
        }
      };
     ....
      //Backend api axios call
     ....

    })
    .then((user) => {
      console.log("TEST G LOGIN 1 "+JSON.stringify(user))
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("....."+JSON.stringify(error))
    });
}
```

got this response, it doesn't inculde

> `accessToken`

```
{
    "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"],
    "serverAuthCode": "4/jwE5LLLLLLa7-f33333jmMD2V978oyp44444eb9yGe_qhHnkXXXXXXXLFXKZlQdDzlH-iIJx_gzqlLLLLLL3Q0PP0",
    "idToken": "...v65a4MCC-ZUQmys_wf_DoCOBJEMuI........",
    "user": {
        "photo": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-tLLLLLyeS0KE/AAAMMMMAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACHi3reMhihoeTe_6NjL666666EUVU82Q/s96-c/photo.jpg",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "familyName": "tech",
        "givenName": "test",
        "name": "testtech",
        "id": "11688888817288868"
    }
}
```

as per [documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin#gettokens)

> getTokens() Resolves with an object containing { idToken: string,
>   accessToken: string, } or rejects with an error. Note that using
>   accessToken is discouraged.

So, i tried this in

```
GoogleSignin.Sign({
....
 var gettoken =  GoogleSignin.currentUserAsync(data.user).then((token) => {
      console.log('USER token', token);
    }).done();
...
 })
```

it got error and also tried `const token = GoogSignIn.getTokens()`, it return `null`.

package.json info

```
{
...
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.9",
    "react-native-firebase": "5.3.1",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^2.0.0"
...
}
```

Please suggest what would be procedure to get accessToken.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally i get accessToken.

**Step 1:-**
I deleted all the generated clidenId in goolge developer console (keep only web application clientId as i used in my web project) and also deleted android app in firebase project.

**Step 2:-**
Created new android app in firebase and download google-services.json and paste it in `android/app/google-services.json`

**Step 3:-**
Copied the clidenId from this part of google-services.json

```
...
  "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "xxxxxxx-xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com", //<--- copied this clientID
              "client_type": 3
            },
            {
              "client_id": "XXXXXXXXXX-fBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBpugnhrade.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 2,
              "ios_info": {
                "bundle_id": "com.projectios"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }

...
```

and paste in

```
GoogleSignin.configure({
  webClientId: 'paste it here',
});
```

**Step 4:-**
This is the code to get accessToken
(But this code was not working in my previous google-services.json file)

```
googleLogin = () => {
 
    GoogleSignin.signIn()
      .then((data) => {

        console.log("TEST " + JSON.stringify(data));

        const currentUser = GoogleSignin.getTokens().then((res)=>{
          console.log(res.accessToken ); //<-------Get accessToken
          var postData = {
            access_token: res.accessToken,
            code: data.idToken,
    
          };
    
          let axiosConfig = {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              "Accept": "application/json",
            }
          };
         -----
          backend api call
         -----
});

      })
      .then((user) => {
        console.log("TEST G LOGIN 1 " + JSON.stringify(user))
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("....." + JSON.stringify(error))
      });   
  }
```

Comment: I was stuck on it for about 1 day, but I was getting errors and suddenly I saw your message, and my problem was solved in just a minute.
Thank you very much!