# React Native Google Authenticate with Django Allauth returns "Incorrect value" (iOS/Android)

Tags: react-native, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I am trying to perform social authentication (with Google) using react native ios and android, with Django on the back end. Note, no firebase is involved here.

**Problem Overview**

React Native Google Signin on the front end returns an (i) access_token and (2) code when the user authenticates with google. Using django rest auth, we send a post request to the back end server and "non_field_errors: ["Incorrect value"] is returned

**Plugins Used:**

[React Native Google Sigin](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin)

[Django All Auth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

[Django Rest Auth](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

**The process**

***Google Cloud Console Setup (OAuth 2.0 Client IDs)*:**

3 Types are setup in Google Cloud Console

- A) Web application (ClientId + Secrete)
- B) Android (only ClientId)
- C) iOS (only ClientId)

***On the Front End (React Native Google Signin)***

```
   async componentDidMount () {
GoogleSignin.configure({
  webClientId: 'ABC-123',    (i.e. A above)
  iosClientId: 'ABC-456',    (i.e. C above)
});
```

}

***On the Back End (Django Allauth)***

1 model object is set up, Google, with A) Web application (ClientId + Secrete) as per google documentation

***User Login via Front End***

When the user authenticates with google in app on their phone, Android or iOS, a token and code is returned. Sending this via Django Rest Auth  {access_token: 'cdeasdlkjla', code:'adkj'} returns "non_field_errors: ["Incorrect value"]

Thoughts!?

Comment: As far as I can see, your setup on the mobile side looks fine. Maybe you haven't set up the back end properly. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48182227/5049799) answer can be helpful

Comment: On the web version, I was using 'react-google-login' the access_token it returned worked fine with the backend. With the same setup iOS/Android keep failing. The I tried swapping the clientids around in the alluath model setup, no luck.

Comment: Thank you Kapobajza, the problem was react native google signin produces id_token on the initial step, not access_token. id_token =/= access_token. Just a few extra lines to get access_token. All good now!

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem, with the help of @Kapobajza response.

Django AllAuth Google Social Auth accepts 'access_token'

React Native Google Sigin's default is 'id_token'

Note that 'access_token' =/= 'id_token'

Therefore, there are two solutions:

1. Backend: Django AllAuth should support id_token. At the time of writing, it does not.
   There is an open ticket here in the link below, which leads to a way to manually support it
   https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1983

Or:

2. FrontEnd: React Native Google Sigin can produce an access token, with just a small step. It is outlined below, Step4

[How to get accessToken of React Native GoogleSignIn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57179401/how-to-get-accesstoken-of-react-native-googlesignin)

Best solution is 2